# jquery, how to create and delete a cookie?

Tags: jquery, cookies

i have some code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    setTimeout(function(){
tb_show('yeah', '#TB_inline?height=490&width=534&inlineId=compare', false);
    },13000);
});
```

what i want is when this script runs a cookie to be created and to expire in 4 days
so that the script wont run unless the cookie has expired.

maybe use something like this:

```
$.cookie("compare", "hello", { expires: 7 });
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: It looks like you figured it out already. What's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set/unset cookie with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: well, i don't know where to set the cookie. and then how to not make the script run if the cookie is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a jQuery plugin that does exactly that:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie